# Axios does not run - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, catch-block

I am using `axios` to make a POST request with React JS, specifically a POST request to the Sendinblue API, found [here](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact). I have tried multiple variations using `axios` however I have not had any luck with successfully completing the POST request.

The code is listed below:

```
var email = this.state.value;
var data = JSON.stringify({ "listIds": [5], "email": email, "attributes": { "SMS": "sms-Number" }, "emailBlacklisted": false, "smsBlacklisted": false, "updateEnabled": true });
var config = {
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts',
     headers: {
         'api-key': 'API-key',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     data: data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
      alert(error);
});
```

I have imported `axios` and the required libraries at the top.

Given this code, I never get an alert when axios is executed. That is, I never get an alert for success or error. So, it seems as if it is not even running the `axios` part.

Any ideas on why this may be? Thank you!

Comment: any error on the console? if you put a console.log before the `axios(config)` is it printed?

Comment: @Berto99 Thanks for your response. I am able to successfully console.log or alert before the `axios(config)` so there does not seem to be an error before the `axios` call.

Comment: Do you see the request been sent to the server on the network tab of (example) google chrome? maybe axios is just waiting to timing out the request

Comment: also, try adding `withCredentials: true` and check if there is maybe a proxy that is blocking you

Comment: your code is fine https://jsfiddle.net/s91j52na/ the error probably happens in code you're not sharing with us

Comment: @DanyAlejandro Thanks for your response. When I run your code, I get the error `Error: Request failed with status code 400`. I have received this same error a couple of times, however I mostly do not receive any alert as described above. Do you know why I may get this error?

Comment: @Berto99 Thank you. I checked the network tab and I do not see any axios request, however I do see the POST request in the network tab. I added the `withCredentials: true` and I still receive the same output.

Comment: Yes, that's unauthorized / malformed request error. Axios is working fine, that is the server's answer you're getting back, prob cause I'm not even using any access token on my request.

Comment: @DanyAlejandro When I insert the access token, however, I still receive that error. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: Probably you're not entering the expected API arguments or they're not in the right format. This is not an Axios problem anymore so you might want to create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I was able to solve this error by placing the button that triggers this code outside of the `form` tag.

**OLD CODE (not working):**

```
<form>
    <TextInput></TextInput>
    <button onClick={this.runCode}>Click here</button>
</form>
```

**NEW CODE (working):**

```
<form>
    <TextInput></TextInput>
</form>
<button onClick={this.runCode}>Click here</button>
```